# Google Play Unsafe Encryption

Tags: android, flutter

Hace varios días la consola de google play me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

**Unsafe Encryption
Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see [this Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9450925) for details.
g0.c.r.q.B**

Mi aplicación está desarrollada en Flutter y el único paquete que utiliza encriptación dentro de mi proyecto es [Flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

He buscado referencias a este problema dentro del package pero no he encontrado nada que me indique a que se hace referencia este patrón **g0.c.r.q.B**

De igual forma se verificó el enlace que nos provee la consola pero no se encuentra nada concreto.

En el package de secure storage me permite definir el tipo de encriptación, se modificó a esto:

```
AndroidOptions(
        encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
        storageCipherAlgorithm: StorageCipherAlgorithm.AES_GCM_NoPadding,
        keyCipherAlgorithm:
            KeyCipherAlgorithm.RSA_ECB_OAEPwithSHA_256andMGF1Padding,
      );
```

Pero continua el problema después de subir nuevamente la aplicación.

```
  flutter_secure_storage: ^6.1.0
```

Comment: La volviste a subir con el cambio?

Comment: Si, y me mostró el mismo mensaje.